# Nesting reactive Angular form into another reactive form

Tags: angular, nested, components, reactive, provider

Which is the best way to nesting an angular component into another angular component?
Both built with reactive approach. I using Angular v16

The parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
 form: FormGroup;

 constructor (private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
   fieldA: [null, []]
   fieldB: [null, []]
   nested: this.formBuilder.group({}),
  }
 }
```

The template of the parent form:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  ...
</form>
```

The nested form:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nested',
  templateUrl: './nested.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nested.component.scss']
})
export class NestedXomponent implements OnInit {
 @Input parentForm: FormGroup;

 nestedForm: FormGroup;


 constructor (private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}


 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.nestedForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   fieldC: [null, []]
   fieldD: [null, []]
  }
  this.parentForm.setControl('nested', this.nestedForm);
 }
```

The template of the parent form:

```
<form [formGroup]="nestedForm">
  ...
</form>
```

I always got

ERROR Error: NG0201: No provider for NgControl found in NodeInjector. parent.component.ts

What I missed, what can be the best way to embed a reactive component to another reactive component?

Comment: You might want to read https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-nested-reactive-forms-using-cvas-b394ba2e5d0d

Comment: Thank you but I interested in what is the real problem with this implementation. If I switch to another way, I never know what was the current problem

Comment: Insert `console.log` calls at the start of both classes' `connector` and `ngOnInit` methods. What's the order they are called in?

Comment: Also, your code lacks info of how you pass in `NestedXomponent.FormGroup`.